# How can I make AppleScript SOAP work with existing SOAP webservices (e.g. W3Schools' CelsiusToFarenheit example)?

Tags: macos, web-services, soap, applescript

I'm currently using AppleScript Editor.
I run the following code there:

```
tell application "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL"
    call soap {method name:"CelsiusToFahrenheit", method namespace uri:"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/", parameters:{Celsius:50 as string}, SOAPAction:"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"}
end tell
```

If I execute the above code, I get an "Error" string back (which is not what I expected).
The generated request is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
          <Celsius xsi:type="xsd:int">50</Celsius>
        </m:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I edit the request like this (I used Fiddler to edit the request):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
        SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
              <Celsius xsi:type="xsd:int">50</Celsius>
            </CelsiusToFahrenheit>
          </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

1. Change "m:CelsiusToFarenheit" to "CelsiusToFarenheit"
2. Change "xmlns:m" to "xmlns"

I receive "122" which is the correct response.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening? Is the SOAP format used by the "call soap" function an old format?
2. Is there a way to fix this (e.g. remove ":m" or "m:" in the request or use different SOAP format through code by setting a parameter in the "call soap" method [i don't know if this is possible])?

Comment: Because it's not really an answer I will put in your comments. 1) no, the m: as SOAP-ENV: are explicit name spacings. Every soap server should support this, also w3school. It's all according to the SOAP 1999 standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skinny:

- A **bug in the `call soap` feature** neglects to namespace-tag the parameters given to a call properly: the method *name* element is prefixed with `m:`, but the *parameter* elements are not.
- The workaround is to **explicitly prefix the parameter names with `m:`**; in the above example, use `|m:Celsius|` instead of `Celsius` - note that the enclosing `|` signs are needed so you can use a name like this that would otherwise break parsing.

**Caveat**: There is a chance that this workaround will break should Apple ever fix the bug.

Applying the workaround to the above example gives us:

```applescript
tell application "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL"
  call soap {method name:"CelsiusToFahrenheit", ¬
            method namespace uri:"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/", ¬
            parameters:{|m:Celsius|:50 as string}, ¬
            SOAPAction:"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"}
end tell
```

---

#### Background:

> 1. (...) Is the SOAP format used by the "call soap" function an old format?

The short of it: AppleScript uses the SOAP **1.1** schema, and while the APIs under the hood also support SOAP 1.2, you cannot select it from *AppleScript* ((you can only do it [from C using Carbon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/soapXMLRPC/chapter4/soapXMLRPC_apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001724-DontLinkElementID_19)))

As described above, the SOAP XML construction has a bug, which is the reason the call didn't work. (The web service at http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx does support 1.1, alongside 1.2).

Here are some clues regarding the importance and maintenance status of the `call soap` and `call xml-rpc` features:

- The features are described in [documentation *separate* from the AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/soapXMLRPC/chapter2/soapXMLRPC_about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001126-//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001721-TPXREF101), even though they appear to be part of the language itself (could not find them in any external dictionaries)
- The documentation was written in 2001 (as of OSX 10.1; and has only seen a tiny revision in 2005; a warning of potentially outdate web-service URL was added :)).

> '2. Is there a way to fix this (e.g. remove ":m" or "m:" in the request or use different SOAP format through code by setting a parameter in the "call soap" method?

(See the workaround above.)

Based on the documentation-status clues, I would not hold my breath for updates or fixes from Apple - which is a pity, because these features look really handy.

Comment: @DjS: My pleasure; glad to hear it. I've submitted a bug report and an enhancement request (for use of SOAP 1.2) to Apple - still not holding my breath, though.

Comment: can I have the bug report id so I can track it too? :D

Comment: @DjS: Unfortunately, bug reports submitted to Apple are not public, so the IDs wouldn't help you. However, I encourage you to submit your own at  http://bugreport.apple.com, which - albeit cumbersome - serves to tell them that more than 1 person is interested in the fix.